# absolute position with float

Tags: html, css

I have arrow buttons as `<<` and `>>` and in between there is a main div block.
This main div has to be `position:absolute` since there are other hidden div elements 
that are overlapped.

The problem I have is with `>>` arrow button that I want to position on the right side of the main div.

This is my [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/anuCAbI/3/edit).

Comment: What about `float:right`? It's floated to the left now

Comment: `float:right` will create huge gap in a big screen.

Answer (score 2):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsbin.com/OXiMikA/3/edit)

```
.pg-wrapper div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position:absolute;
}

.left {
  display:inline-block
}

.pg-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @Seong Lee Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I floated to the arrow to the right, and set a parent around the div.  it seems to have done what you wanted ( this time ).

http://jsbin.com/izeHiVu/2/

```
 .right {
     position:relative;
     display: block;
     float:right;
  }

.wrapper { width:265px; }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the input but I want it near to the main div not with huge distance in a big screen.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Height and Width in pg-wrapper css class

```
like this
        .pg-wrapper {
                 float:left;
                 height:27px;
                 width:188px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uSfVS/3/)**

**css**

```
   ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-step li {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav-step li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 14px;
  z-index: -1
}

.nav-step li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.nav-step .active {
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
}

.pg-wrapper div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position:absolute;
}

.left {
  display:inline-block;
    margin:0 -3px;
    padding:0;
}

.pg-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
    margin:0 -4px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I mentioned that div block has to have `position:absolute` since there has to be other overlapped/hidden div blocks in the same position.